# Suppress triggering Seahorse from the command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnupg

I think that [Seahorse](https://live.gnome.org/Seahorse) is a good idea. But there are times when I don't want it.

The following example triggers Gnome/Seahorse.

```
echo "FOO" > readme.txt
gpg -c --symmetric --passphrase secret readme.txt
```

Can I prevent this from happening on the command line only for this
example?

Thankful for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is is:

```
gpg --batch -c --passphrase secret readme.txt
```

(For the record, that popup has nothing to do with Seahorse.)

Comment: No prob! PS: I'm sure you're already aware of the dangers of using `--passphrase` on a multi-user system, so I won't bore you, but for anyone else reading this: *don't use `--passphrase` unless you're the only one on your system when you run it (also keep in mind this will likely save the passphrase to your shell history).*